# Writing a header with spaces are lost after knitting to MS Word?

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I type a header in rmarkdown with a multiple spaces between words(I intent to make one word a each side of the page), all the spaces are removed and left with single space.

Any Ideas how to fix it when knit for MS word?

```
'''
## First                      Second
'''
```

Result:

### First                      Second

the word file will be : "First Second"

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example in r](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The link I provided, will tell you how. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit the question accordingly. You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us the code, input, output, and if any, errors. Cheers.

Comment: This is standard markdown behavior: in the middle of a line, multiple spaces are equivalent to one space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution eventually. It is to add `&nbsp;`characters to fill the void space and keep it.